# Film counter says wrong number

Tags: film

I’ve just loaded my film and the film counter says 15 although I haven’t taken any photos yet? Have I loaded it wrong/will this ruin my roll?

Comment: You may want to state the camera model.

Comment: What kind/model of camera? What film format (135/35mm, 120/6x4.5, etc.)? What did the counter say before you started loading the film?